# Why can't I provide default implementations for Type functions returning Self in protocol when using inheritance?

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols, swift-protocols

Why doesn't this work:

```
protocol Work {
    init()
    static func make() -> Self
}

extension Work {
    static func make() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

class Foo : Work {
    required init() {}
}
```

I can make inheritance possible by adding the factory to the object itself:

```
class Foo : Work {
    required init() {}

    static func make() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}
```

I could also use a non-class or mark the class `final`, but I'd prefer/am required  to use inheritance.

Is it possible to implement a default factory on a protocol so that an inheritable type can conform without implementing it again.

Comment: What does "work" mean (as in "doesn't work" or "make it work")?

Comment: I clarified in the question @matt, sorry about that. "Work" in this context means an inheritable object is able to conform without duplicating the class level constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a factory that will initialize objects adhering to a protocol, you should use the always awesome [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)! 
E.g.

```
protocol Work {
    init()
    static func make<T: Work>(type: T.Type) -> T
}

extension Work {
    static func make<T: Work>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return T.init()
    }
    static func make() -> Self {
        return make(Self)
    }
}

class Foo : Work {
    required init() {}
}
```

Comment: Your answer didn't quite do what I wanted, but it did lead me to the right solution w/ a few minor tweaks! I made edits onto your answer :) Thanks again!

Comment: Although, this does create some other complications where objects may be asked to create objects outside of their inheritance tree. I think it's still the best I can achieve at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem because unfortunately, the conformer should be able to define how it's created. Being able to ask any conformer to create any other conformer is problematic. Still +1 for an interesting approach :)

Comment: Isn't that what init's for in the first place?